# Python Requests: Connect to Sharepoint online with 2-factor auth enabled

Tags: python, sharepoint

I would like to create a Python script to retrieve lists from Sharepoint Online and potentially update them. I can do all of this from the browser just fine. However, I'm having a hard time connecting to Sharepoint using the Requests module. When I navigate to https://mysharepoint.sharepoint.com, I get redirected to the https://login.microsoftonline.com to log in through my account. The login mechanism also requires two-factor authentication.

I'm not sure whether there's a way I could log in using Python at all at this point. Most of the packages I've tried have not been able to authenticate my user.

Comment: Usually, if a service that requires 2-FA wants to allow access through a script it gives you ways of generating an API Key of some kind for that particular script, IP... (like a "restricted" password, to name it somehow) I don't know if that will be the case of `sharepoint.com`, but maybe it's worth taking a quick look to your account options?

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking on setting up an API key, oauth mechanisms, ... but so far no luck. If anyone could provide pointers on getting an API key set up. I really just want to use the permissions that I have granted to my user, I don't think this should require admin rights to the entire sharepoint online instance...

Comment: Office365 app passwords work for me in order to get around two-factor authentication. Creating them is a bit hidden in the settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords

Besides, consider using the `shareplum` library instead of using Sharepoint's REST API directly. Most common operations like listing and updating files will be much simpler this way.
https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#office-365-authentication